# Bounds on near-zero integer linear combinations of numbers linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots$ be an infinite sequence of real numbers such that any finite subset is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $f(N)$ be the number of tuples $(m_1, \dots, m_N)$ with $m_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $|m_i| \leq N$.
 for which
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{N} m_i \alpha_i \right|< \frac{1}{N^{100}}.$$

(where 100 could be your favorite constant, or maybe something sublinear if that's not possible). Is there any known way to put an asymptotic upper bound on $f(N)$ better than the trivial one of $(2N+1)^N$?

For concreteness (or if it makes the question possible to answer!) you could take the $\alpha_i$ to be the square roots of square free integers (ordered however you like, although I do have a particular ordering in mind). If that doesn't work, any effectively computable $\alpha_i$ would be welcome.

It seems that one *might* be able to say something of the sort using [Evertse's quantitative subspace theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2268) but it isn't really clear to me how. Any pointers (or even conjectures) here would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I just noticed something, though it's not super useful: If one takes $\alpha_1 = 1$, $\alpha_k = \log p_k$ ($p_k$ the $k$th prime), then for large $N$, for each $i$ it cannot be the case that just $m_1$ and $m_i$ are non-zero by [a quantitative Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker's_theorem#Extensions). So we have at least $f(N) \leq (2N + 1)^N - (N-1)(2N+1)^2$. This isn't super useful for me since this has the same asymptotics as the trivial bound, but might be helpful to think about.

Comment: Interesting question, but you probably want to specify it more, otherwise one can say that $f(N)\leq(2N+1)^N$ is a trivial upper bound.

Comment: Well, if $\alpha_1=1$, then for any choice of $m_2,\dots,m_N$ there is at most one good choice of $m_1$, so in this case $f(N)\leq (2N+1)^{N-1}$. This is still trivial, of course.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lower bound $f(N)>N^{N-101}$. To see this suppose without loss that $\alpha_1=1$. Then consider all the $N^{N-1}$ values of $\sum_{i=2}^{N} m_i\alpha_i\bmod 1$ with $|m_i|\leq N/2$. There is an interval of length $N^{-100}$, which contains at least $N^{N-101}$ of these values, and taking differences we obtain $N^{N-101}$ sums $\left|\sum_{i=2}^{N} (m_i-m'_i)\alpha_i\bmod 1\right|<N^{-100}$ with $|m_i-m_i'|\leq N$.

In general there is a matching upper bound. Suppose that your sequence has the property that the discrepancy of $\{\sum_{i=2}^{1000} m_i\alpha_i\bmod 1: |m_i|<N\}$ is $\mathcal{O}(N^{-100})$. Then no matter how you choose $m_{1001}, \ldots, m_N$, the first 1000 coefficients are determined in $\ll N^{899}$ ways, so you get an upper bound of magnitude $(2N+1)^{N-101}$. So there is a matching upper bound for almost all sequences. I don't know about a concrete example, but there is a vast literature on discrepancy, and linear combinations of irrational numbers is sufficiently natural so that someone has probably treated it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! One thing I don't quite see though is how you handle the fact that in these sums with $< N^{-100}$ fractional part, the integer part may be on the order of $N^2$ ($N$ terms in the sum times a maximum value of $N$ for $|m_i - m_i'|$) and even really $N^3$ if we assume that $|\alpha_n|$ is on the order of $n$. In this case we won't be able to cancel out the integer part since $|m_1|$ can be at most $N$. I guess you could run this argument with $|m_i| < N^{1/3}$ and get a similar lower bound, but would there be a corresponding upper bound?